# Identify date between multiple optional intervals in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a python dataframe looks like this, it contains a lot of date columns with sparse filled values, not necessarily sorted from left to right. Can't get rid of the NaN columns because it may contain sparse value for some IDs.

| ID | production date | date1 | date2 | date3 | date4 | date5 | date6 | date7 | date8 | date9 | date10 | date11 | date 12 | date13 | date 14 | date 15 | date 16 | date17 | date 18 | date 19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aa | 6/18/2022 | 4/20/2022 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 11/14/2022 | 12/12/2022 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 6/15/2022 | nan | nan | nan | 8/29/2022 | nan | 10/10/2022 |
| bb | 11/25/2021 | 5/25/2021 | nan | nan | nan | 9/15/2021 | 11/20/2021 | 12/20/2021 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 8/29/2021 | nan | 10/15/2021 |
| CC | 6/20/2022 | 4/25/2022 | nan | nan | nan | nan | 11/14/2022 | 12/12/2022 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 8/29/2022 | nan | 10/10/2022 |
| dd | 7/30/2020 | 3/25/2020 | nan | 12/15/2019 | nan | nan | 10/14/2020 | 11/12/2020 | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | nan | 7/29/2020 | nan | 9/10/2020 |

What i'm trying to achieve is to find window of production date falls between which two dates. Take an example, for ID aa, production date is 6/18/2022, it falls between the window of date13 6/15/2022 and date17 8/29/2022, and i want to mark it in the bucket of date13. And for ID bb, the production date falls between date6 and date7, and i want to mark it in bucket of date6. Output examples are in the last column.

What would be the best way to achieve descired output in python? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "i want to mark it in the bucket of date13"?

Comment: i mean i want to label it as date13, to identify the phase of the production date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to get the column name of the *closest date* to production's ? If so, you can use :

```
df["output"] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(
                    lambda x: (pd.to_datetime(x) -pd.to_datetime(x)["production date"])
                        .abs().drop("production date").idxmin(), axis=1)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   ID production date      date1  date2  ...     date17  date 18     date 19  output
0  aa       6/18/2022  4/20/2022    NaN  ...  8/29/2022      NaN  10/10/2022  date13
1  bb      11/25/2021  5/25/2021    NaN  ...  8/29/2021      NaN  10/15/2021   date6
2  CC       6/20/2022  4/25/2022    NaN  ...  8/29/2022      NaN  10/10/2022   date1
3  dd       7/30/2020  3/25/2020    NaN  ...  7/29/2020      NaN   9/10/2020  date17
```

***Update :***

> the window i mean **the smallest window** it falls within, i.e. produciton
> date is 6/18/2022, the smallest window it falls within is between
> date13 6/15/2022 to date17 8/19/2022. And i want to label it with the
> column name of that beginning date of the window, which is date13.

```
def smallest_window(ser):
    diff = (pd.to_datetime(ser) - pd.to_datetime(ser)["production date"]).dt.days
    left_date = diff.loc[lambda x: x.lt(0)].idxmax() #.le(0) to make it inclusive
    right_date = diff.loc[lambda x: x.gt(0)].idxmin() #.ge(0) to make it inclusive
    return [left_date, right_date]
​
df["date_intervals"] = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(smallest_window, axis=1)
df["date_col_names"] = df["date_intervals"].str[0] # use `.str[1]` to get the last date
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

   ID production date      date1  ...     date 19     date_intervals  date_col_names
0  aa       8/18/2022  4/20/2022  ...  10/10/2022   [date13, date17]          date13
1  bb      11/25/2021  5/25/2021  ...  10/15/2021     [date6, date7]           date6
2  CC       6/20/2022  4/25/2022  ...  10/10/2022    [date1, date17]           date1
3  dd       7/30/2020  3/25/2020  ...   9/10/2020  [date17, date 19]          date17
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer! One clarification is i'm not looking for closest date, i'm looking for the window production date falls into and flag it with the start date column of that window. i.e. if ID aa production date is 6/10/2022, it falls within the window of date1 4/20/2022 and date13 6/15/2022, and i want to mark the beginning of the window production date falls into, which is date1 in this case. Hope this helps explain. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but the logic is still not clear for me. In the example you shared in your question, for the id `aa`, there is so many possibilities. How do you decide/choose which interval ?
The `production date` *18-Jun-2022* falls `1)` between *20-Apr-2022* and *14-Nov-2023*, `2)` between *15-Jun-2022* and *10-Oct-2022* and there is many others..

Comment: Oh i see your point, the window i mean the smallest window it falls within, i.e. produciton date is 6/18/2022, the smallest window it falls within is between date13 6/15/2022 to date17 8/19/2022. And i want to label it with the column name of that beginning date of the window, which is date13.

Comment: Then, my approach should work for you. Can you explain why it isn't ?

Comment: Sure, if we change the production date of id aa to 8/18/2022, your approach will label this record date17 8/19/2022 as it's the closest to this date, but the desired output is to label it the beginning of this smallest window which should be date13(smallest window is date13 6/15/2022 to date17 8/19/2022).

Comment: Fair enough ;) I updated my answer, can you check it out ?

Comment: Great! It worked! I added two columns one for today's date, another for 1900/01/01 to handle some cases there's only one date value other than production date, and it totoally works! Thank you so much :)